# Issue with SELECT TOP 1

Tags: c#, sql, sql-server, t-sql, sql-server-2008-r2

I am using C#, ASP.NET, SQL Server 2008 R2.  My code is pretty simple, but I keep running into the same error.

I have a table `Bids` that has the columns `OfferAmount` and `Status`.
The `Status` is either "Active" or "Red".  I want to calculate the average `OfferAmount` of the rows in the table that have `Status = 'Active'` and compare it to a preset value.  If the calculated average `OfferAmount` is lower than the preset value, I then set the `Status` of the row with current `Status = 'Active'` AND with the lowest `OfferAmount` to 'Red'.  I then re-run the process. I use a do/while loop with the condition that the `calculated average > preset value.`

Everything works perfectly, except for one condition. If I have two `OfferAmounts` that are equal AND I need to set both of their `Status = 'Red'` (so they are no longer part of my calculation for Status = 'Active').

In that case, my loop sets one `OfferAmount` to `Status = 'Red'`, but it then skips the other `OfferAmount`. By skip, I mean it behaves as if it doesn't exist and moves on to the next highest `OfferAmount`. So I am left with a row that has its Status = 'Active'. It keeps going and marks the rest of the rows 'Red' above and below the value, but never comes back to that row.

This is the command I am using:

```
UPDATE Bids 
   SET Status = 'Red' 
 WHERE BidId IN (SELECT TOP 1 BidId 
                   FROM Bids 
                  WHERE Status = 'Active' 
                    AND ItemId = @ItemId 
               ORDER BY OfferAmount, BidDateAndTime DESC)
```

I tried a bunch of different sql commands that all worked except in this one case.  I am beginning to think that it is a configuration issue.

Answer (score 3):

You could do your comparison on the minimum bid amount, i.e.

```
UPDATE Bids SET 
  Status = 'Red' 
WHERE Status = 'Active' AND 
      ItemId = @ItemId AND  
      OfferAmount = (SELECT MIN(OfferAmount) 
                     FROM Bids 
                     WHERE Status = 'Active' AND 
                           ItemId = @ItemId
```

I haven't tried it but the idea should work.

Answer (score 1):

If you add `WITH TIES` after [`TOP n`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms189463.aspx) you can get additional rows (resulting in more than `n` in total) that tie with the `n`-th row based on the values of the columns in the ORDER BY clause:

```
UPDATE Bids 
SET Status = 'Red' 
WHERE BidId in 
      (SELECT TOP 1 WITH TIES BidId 
       FROM Bids 
       WHERE Status = 'Active' 
         AND ItemId = @ItemId 
       ORDER BY OfferAmount)
```

Comment: This would be my idea too +1 Minimal changes to the query too,

Answer (score 0):

thanks for the help.  I didn't end up using it because before I saw your reply, I split it into two separate sql commands.  1st one retrieved the row ID using the same Select Top 1 Where statement I used before.  The second command then set the Status of that row ID to 'Red'.

Either breaking it up fixed it or I wasn't putting it together as a single command correctly.

Thanks for the ideas!